# Deno -> How do I run the codes to run without errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I'd like to import from local

Testing environment Deno v1.6.0

I've tried local import by Deno lang

Local directory

```
.
└── src
    └── sample
        ├── hello_world.ts
        ├── httpRequest.ts
        ├── localExport
        │       └── arithmetic.ts
        ├── localImport.ts
```

'./localExport/arithmetic.ts' File to be imported

```
function add(outbound: number, inbound: number): number {
  return outbound + inbound
}

function multiply(sum: number, tax: number): number {
  return sum * tax
}
```

'./localImport.ts' File to run

```
import { add, multiply } from "./localImport/arithmetic.ts";

function totalCost(outbound: number, inbound: number, tax: number): number {
  return multiply(add(outbound, inbound), tax);
}

console.log(totalCost(19, 31, 1.2));
console.log(totalCost(45, 27, 1.15));
```

Run the above codes

```
❯ deno run src/sample/localImportExport.ts
```

I got the errors:

```
❯ deno run src/sample/localImportExport.ts 
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './localImport/arithmetic.ts' does not provide an export named 'add'
import { add, multiply } from "./localImport/arithmetic.ts";
         ~~~
    at <anonymous> (file:///Users/ko-kamenashi/Desktop/Samples/Deno/deno-sample/src/sample/localImportExport.ts:1:10)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is unclear about the error message you provided? The file you’re including doesn’t export anything called `add`, so it throws an error. This question is impossible to answer without seeing the source for `arithmetic.ts`.

Comment: @esqew I'm sorry to forget codes of import source file. I added target codes.

Comment: Can you cite the source on which you’re basing your implicit assumption that you can import arbitrary functions from external files that haven’t been properly `export`ed? That’s exactly the issue the error message is pointing to (you also still haven’t provided any color on what specifically you don’t understand about the error message itself).

Comment: @esqew Thanks for your advice!. I resolved this question By adding export keyword to the target function.
```
export function add(outbound: number, inbound: number): number {
  return outbound + inbound
}

export function multiply(sum: number, tax: number): number {
  return sum * tax
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `The requested module './localImport/arithmetic.ts' does not provide an export named 'add'` telling you that you should use `export`

Just add the following line to end of your file `export {add, multiply}

'./localExport/arithmetic.ts' File to be imported

```
function add(outbound: number, inbound: number): number {
  return outbound + inbound
}

function multiply(sum: number, tax: number): number {
  return sum * tax
}

export {add, multiply}
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching the solution. this problem resolved.